# Java pattern matcher find multiple strings

Tags: java, regex

I am using `Pattern.compile()` to find if a text string contains two other strings. But it needs to be in one regex pattern.

For example the string must have "StringOne" and "StringTwo" in it.

I could do `Pattern.compile("(StringOne StringTwo|StrinTwo StringOne")`, but both strings are quite long and I want to see if I can compress it.

If I do `"(StringOne )?StringTwo( StringOne)?"` it would match "StringTwo" and "StringOne StringTwo StringOne".

Comment: what's wrong with just using String.contains() twice?

Comment: Does it need to be a regex, because I can think of quite a few different ways to do it, that may be more efficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
^(?=.*\\bStringOne\\b)(?=.*\\bStringTwo\\b)
```

This uses two look-aheads anchored to start of input to assert that both strings appear *somewhere*

Edit:
Added  word boundaries `\b` to ends of strings to prevent matches of one string within another, although this was not a stated requirement of the question.

Comment: Note that this allows the possibility of overlapping, while the one with `|` in the question doesn't.

Comment: @nhahtdh what exactly do you mean by "overlapping"? Give an example of what you mean.

Comment: If StringOne is `assortment` and StringTwo is `sort`, your regex will allow `"assortment"` to match.

Comment: @nhahtdh so what? I've added a "fix" for your comment, but I don't think it's required. I think that assortment should pass the test of a string containing both sort and assortment.

Comment: It depends on the requirement. I just want to point out an essential difference between listing out all the permutations and using look-ahead.

Answer (score 0):

There is question of speed. 
You could probably use lookaheads to accomplish this, but it's costly speed-wise. lookaheads are really expansive on long strings.

If the strings are long, the faster approach would be to do two separate matches.

If you really need to do one, use your original way `string A string B|String B String A`